# Balanced Feistel networks: Are there any lower bounds on the computational complexity of breaking a $k$-round Feistel cipher?

Tags: provable-security, complexity, feistel-network

[This paper by Patarin](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-45682-1_14.pdf) presents an attack (section 9) on balanced Feistel networks with $k$ rounds, where the input is a bit-string is of length $2n$. (Since it is balanced, this means each PRF takes as input a bit-string of length $n$).

In this attack, the adversary is able to distinguish a $k$-round Feistel network permutation from a uniformly chosen even-signature permutation with computation $\mathcal{O}(2^{n(\frac{k^2}{2}-4k+8)})$. (Actually distinguishes generators of such permutations.)

Is there a lower bound on the amount of computation required to distinguish a $k$-round balanced Feistel permutation from a random even-signature permutation?

Comment: please include in the question the definition of $n$

Comment: @kodlu Good point. Updated.